# How to save in a safely way private keys in Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Tags: cryptography, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have seen that in the released projects (like Supply Chain) an off-chain database is used to save the user's information and state data. Is it possible to avoid using this database to save user information or is an implicit pattern of Sawtooth applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private keys must be stored securely.  At a minimum that means making the private key file unreadable to everyone but the owner (uw+o or 0600 permission). It is also a good idea to restrict access to the machine storing the private keys, if possible.

Better yet, use a software or hardware keystore (such as a hardware HSM).

Sawtooth does not store private keys in the global state or any database.

Public keys, which are not used for signing (just verification) are present in transactions and the blockchain.

Comment: thanks Dan! I noticed that the Supply Chain uses a RethinkDB off-chain where the encrypted private key is saved and I can not understand why since the Client signing model uses the user's key locally while here a POST is needed to the Server's API for recovery (even if the key is sent encrypted on the network).